# Replace all tags below a node

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to change all tags below a node in transformation.
Source XML looks like this:

```
<Address>
<s:name>name</s:name>
<s:lastName>last name <a:lastName>
<s:address1>Address Line 1</s:address1>
<s:address2>Address Line 2</s:address2>
```

Required O/p:

```
<Address>

<name>name</name>

<lastName>last name <lastName>

<address1>Address Line 1</address1>

<address2>Address Line 2</address2>
```

There are thousand of tags.So, can not write match to all. Is there a way I can take top level node and handle all tags below?

Comment: 1. Your source XML is not XML (and neither is your requested output). --  2. Please pick either XSLT 1.0 **or** 2.0, not both.  -- 3. What exactly is your difficulty here? Seems all you need to do is convert each tag to an element, using `local-name()` as its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `match="/*//*"` then you match all descendant elements of the root element. Then you can construct a new element using

`<xsl:template match="/*//*"><xsl:element name="local-name()"><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node ()"/></xsl:element></xsl:template>`

Then add the identity transformation template to your code and you are done.